# Why objects with cloth modifier don't move after I parent them to moving empty?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, parent

I created the mast of a ship with a sail, flag and several ropes. Sail, flag and some ropes have cloth modifier.

I parent them all to empty, but when I move empty, only the mast and ropes without the cloth modifier moves. And all of the objects that have cloth modifier remain in place. It looks parent does not work with them.

I am allready using pinned vertices, it works fine. But I need to be able to move the mast with a sail, not sail separately from the mast.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: @Jerryno no, this problem is different. I am allready using pinned vertices, it works fine. But I need to be able to move the mast with a sail, not sail separately from the mast.

Comment: Ok then. You didn't play the animate button. You need to re-simulate. Makes sense now?

Comment: @Jerryno Yes, it works, thank you very much! :) If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, yep I'll add it so there is more answered questions on site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are pinned vertices in the cloth and the object doesn't move, a previous simulation is cached and blender is using this old cached data.

The simulation needs to be refreshed by playing the timeline or re-baking the simulation.